# C# : Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model named StorePage that has 2 properties that can contain multiple attribute values, I declared them as arrays to later on a method in the controller iterate through a data reader, get the values from the database/ table column put them in these arrays and make them accessible to my front end app.

```
public class StorePage
{
    public int ActionTypeID { get; set; }
    public int ResultTypeID { get; set; }
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }
    public int StorePageID { get; set; }
    public int SPPreambleID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SEOTitle { get; set; }
    public int ParentStorePageID { get; set; }
    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string ImageLink { get; set; }
    public string Blurb { get; set; }
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string Footer { get; set; }

    // these are the arrays
    public int[] SPAttributeRefID { get; set; }
    public int[] AttributeID { get; set; }

}
```

// This below is the method that gets the values from the database.

```
    public StorePage GetPage(int StorePageID, int SPPreambleID)
    {
        StorePage storepage = new StorePage();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DEV_BI01_LVT"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mn_StorePage_GetPage", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StorePageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = StorePageID;

                if (SPPreambleID != -1)                    
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPPreambleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = SPPreambleID;
                }
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        storepage.StorePageID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        storepage.Title = (reader.IsDBNull(1)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(1);
                        storepage.SEOTitle = (reader.IsDBNull(2)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(2);
                        storepage.ParentStorePageID = (reader.IsDBNull(3)) ? -1 : reader.GetInt32(3);
                        storepage.Meta = (reader.IsDBNull(4)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(4);
                        storepage.SPPreambleID = (reader.IsDBNull(5)) ? -1 : reader.GetInt32(5);
                        storepage.Image = (reader.IsDBNull(6)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(6);
                        storepage.ImageLink = (reader.IsDBNull(7)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(7);
                        storepage.Blurb = (reader.IsDBNull(8)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(8);
                        storepage.RegionID = (reader.IsDBNull(9)) ? -1 : reader.GetInt32(9);
                        storepage.Footer = (reader.IsDBNull(10)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(10);

                        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                        {
                            storepage.SPAttributeRefID = reader.GetInt32(11);
                        }

                    }
            }
        }
        return storepage;
    }
```

The line within the For loop is giving me an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

```
storepage.SPAttributeRefID = reader.GetInt32(11);
```

Is it possible someone can try to help me resolve this problem? I am probably missing a cast or perhaps there is a better way to get and store the values. The relationship between the page and the attribute values is of one to many. A page can have multiple attributes  in my case this are instruments, and styles, and scoring.

Here is an example of what I am trying to retrieve:

```
23  trumpet seo 7   meta    26  trumpet.jpg /store/trumpet.jpg  blurb   3   footer  1   506
23  trumpet seo 7   meta    26  trumpet.jpg /store/trumpet.jpg  blurb   3   footer  2   183
23  trumpet seo 7   meta    26  trumpet.jpg /store/trumpet.jpg  blurb   3   footer  3   45
```

The last column is the attributes column. You can see these are 3 different values pertaining to a single page record.

For your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to add the int to the array or did you define it wrong and it should not be an array to begin with and just an int?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your last edit. This is one way to handle it and it assumes that the only difference in the results are those last two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way. This assumes that the last 2 columns (12,13) are the items that belong to the arrays. Note that you now have a list instead of an array as these are easier to grow where as an array has a fixed size.

```
public class StorePage
{
    public StorePage(){
        SPAttributeRefID = new List<int>();
        AttributeID = new List<int>();
    }
   // these are now Lists
    public List<int> SPAttributeRefID { get; set; }
    public List<int> AttributeID { get; set; }

}

public StorePage GetPage(int StorePageID, int SPPreambleID)
{
    StorePage storepage = null;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DEV_BI01_LVT"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mn_StorePage_GetPage", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StorePageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = StorePageID;

        if (SPPreambleID != -1)                    
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPPreambleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = SPPreambleID;
        }
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();

        using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // create a new instance if not created yet
            if(storepage == null)
            {
                storepage = new StorePage();
                storepage.StorePageID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                storepage.Title = (reader.IsDBNull(1)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(1);
                storepage.SEOTitle = (reader.IsDBNull(2)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(2);
                storepage.ParentStorePageID = (reader.IsDBNull(3)) ? -1 : reader.GetInt32(3);
                storepage.Meta = (reader.IsDBNull(4)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(4);
                storepage.SPPreambleID = (reader.IsDBNull(5)) ? -1 : reader.GetInt32(5);
                storepage.Image = (reader.IsDBNull(6)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(6);
                storepage.ImageLink = (reader.IsDBNull(7)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(7);
                storepage.Blurb = (reader.IsDBNull(8)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(8);
                storepage.RegionID = (reader.IsDBNull(9)) ? -1 : reader.GetInt32(9);
                storepage.Footer = (reader.IsDBNull(10)) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(10);
            }
            // only read the columns 12,13 and add each respective member to the corresponding list
            if(!reader.IsDBNull(11))
                storepage.SPAttributeRefID.Add(reader.GetInt32(11));
            if(!reader.IsDBNull(12))
                storepage.AttributeID.Add(reader.GetInt32(12));
        }
    }
    return storepage;
}
```

Comment: Hi Igor. Thank you for your code. It looks good and I am going to try it. I have one question only, can a check for null be added before adding the 2 new members?

Comment: @erasmocarlos - Yes, if its a `nullable` column then absolutely you should check for a null value. I updated the code.

Comment: Igor, oh man, your code worked right away. I can access the attribute values! Such a relief. Thank you so much.

Comment: @erasmocarlos - Cool, glad it worked for you! Please consider accepting it as the answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)).

Comment: I will accept it as the working answer for my case. Is there any way I can also recognize the help that other people offered even if not the accepted solution?

Comment: @erasmocarlos - Yes, you can upvote all the answers you thought were helpful using the up arrow next to the answer including the answer you marked as the answer. And you can mark a single answer in the question as the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 7):

The error is self-explanatory. The property `SPAttributeRefID` is an `int[]`:

```
public int[] SPAttributeRefID { get; set; }
```

The result of `reader.GetInt32(11);` is an `int`.

If you want to fill that array with the value then:

```
storepage.SPAttributeRefID = new int[] { reader.GetInt32(11) };
```

---

By this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    storepage.SPAttributeRefID = reader.GetInt32(11);
}
```

I think you want to fill the array with 3 items from different columns. You can do:

```
storepage.SPAttributeRefID = new int[] 
{  
    reader.GetInt32(11),  
    reader.GetInt32(12),  
    reader.GetInt32(13)
};

//Or:
storepage.SPAttributeRefID = Enumerable.Range(11,3)
                                       .Select(x => reader.GetInt32(x));
```

---

After your update: What you should do is use the first suggestion I gave and then later on use Linq to `GroupBy` the results. Each iteration of the `while` loop processes 1 record and what you are trying to achieve is between records. Another option is to use linq to entities via some ORM and to do this `GroupBy` in the database itself.

Comment: @erasmo carlos - also please explain what you are trying to do with the loop because it is difficult to understand. Do you want the same value 3 times? Do you want to read different columns, and 3 of them?

Comment: I think he wants to add it to 3 different indices of SPAttributeRefID.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error. I was not sure I was doing it correctly. I am going to make the recommended changes and see if I can get it right.

Comment: @GiladGreen, I added an example from a record in the database, that has 3 different values in the AttributeRefId column.

Comment: @erasmocarlos - That is quite a different question then :)..... See my update with suggestion on what do to.

Comment: I apologize, I was trying my best to explain my problem. I your first suggestion this line?: 
storepage.SPAttributeRefID = new int[] { reader.GetInt32(11) };

Comment: @erasmo Carlos - ya :) use that line and have the object you are building added to a list. Then after the while loop use GroupBy to group the different rows and merge all these int[] that contain 1 value